# How to always checking for date and time in database with system date and time

Tags: android, notifications

I have class MianActivity to to allow user choose date and time from date&timePicker. User are able to choose the date and time and pressed "set reminder".
When user pressed "set reminder" button, date and time will store to my database.
I have do the check for the date and time in database with current system milliseconds, notification will show when date&time matched with the system one. The problem i faced is it only check for once, if not matched it will stop the whole notification..Any way to make it always checking??

This is the code get day and time from user:

```
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String message = editmsg.getText().toString();  //get String from textbox
            //set DatePicker of user choosen
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());

            //set timePicker
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

            //DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
            //String date = df.format(calendar.getTime());
            long date = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

Afterward i will called 2 function:

```
         storeData(date,message);

            checkReminder();
```

Here is my checkReminder class

```
      long current = System.currentTimeMillis();

    DatabaseHandler cdb = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
    cdb.open();

    Cursor dateAll = cdb.getAllDate(); 
    if(dateAll.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Log.v("getting data","getting data");
            long date = dateAll.getLong(1);

            if(date== current){

                matchDate(date);
            }


         } while (dateAll.moveToNext());
    }
```

Here is my matchDate class

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    intent.setClass(MainActivity.this,MyNortification.class);
    intent.putExtra("msg", message);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //show notification when date & time meet.
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date, pendingIntent);
```

Hope some one help me....

Comment: check out [this guide at developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

Comment: I am need to create database to store each of the reminder/alarm? Or by using the alarm service no need to store the date and time to database?